# can't connect to RDS instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I'm trying to connect to my AWS RDS Instance but i keep getting this error :
[image]

The public access is already set to public :

[image]

Comment: Do you probably need to allow inbound connections on the port used by your instance?

Answer (score 0):

As per snapshot, it throws connection timeout. Check your security group for inbound connectivity for 3306 port.